# google's Geolocation api returns my location not the cell tower's location

Tags: c#, google-geolocation

I have read that this is because the cell tower cannot be found in the database but I tried the details on CellIdFinder and it found it.

I don't get an error, I get my location. Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be using your gps rather than cell tower triangulation? In that case it wouldn't need to know the location of the tower, but could still tell you where you were.

Comment: No there is no gps being sent. Thank you for your time but the error was in my code. I wasn't using flush() on a write stream.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute called considerIp, if it is true, google will return your location if it cannot find the location of what you are searching for. If you don't provide that key, it will be `true` by default. So put this in your request body : `considerIp : false`